# Customizing itemize in beamer?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I have the following in the preamble :

```
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=red}  
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}  
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]  
\newenvironment{myenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[(1)]}{\end{enumerate}} .
```

Itemize works as intended when it is not called inside any other environment, however if I have an itemize inside `myenumerate`, I see blue circles instead of red triangles as the symbols marking the item elements: how can I get red triangles instead?

Comment: (hint: use four spaces to format code as such (or highlight it and press the `101010`-button))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your `itemize` is inside an `enumerate`, the nested level increases by one and a different template/color is used.  So add:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Can I ask a subquestion? How you can change only one item. For example to emphasize one line in enumerate/itemize list.

Comment: If you want to "alert" the entire item you can do `\item<alert@1-> ...`.  Or if you want to change the symbol you can change the template inside a group.  If you go into more detail with your own question I can answer in more detail.

Comment: See the question and answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4797/215 for some clues as to how to play with beamer itemize...